# Displaying image without waitKey

Tags: python, opencv

This Python code displayed an image in full screen:

```
blank_image = cv2.imread('blank.jpg')
cv2.namedWindow("bw", cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN)          
cv2.setWindowProperty("bw", cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, cv2.cv.CV_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)
cv2.imshow("bw", blank_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

The problem is the code is going to run on a Linux machine without keyboard. Calling waitKey means the UI processing will not be done until a key event occurs, and thus the contradiction.

Is there any way beside the waitKey, then?

Comment: cv2.waitKey(1) won't block

Answer (score 13):

Just to clarify: from the [docs](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#waitkey) you can see that

> Python: cv2.waitKey([delay]) → retval
>
> The function waitKey waits for a key event infinitely (when
> delay <= 0 ) or for delay milliseconds, when it is positive.

If you use the `delay = 0`, then your program waits for a key event **infinitely**, blocking the execution. As @Miki said, you can use `delay = 1`, so that `waitKey` won't block.

Comment: Coming here a few years later but I'm facing this issue.  Setting `delay = 1` is not the same as not having a wait, is there any way to use `cv2.imshow` without waitKey?

Comment: @Apollys Unfortunately, not that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `matplotlib` library for displaying images in python.

```
In [9]: blank_image = cv2.imread('blank.jpg')
In [10]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
In [11]: plt.ion()
In [12]: plt.imshow(blank_image)
Out[12]: <matplotlib.image.AxesImage at 0x7fb3cf31bf10>
```

Comment: cv2 reads the image as a bgr array, pyplot is expecting a rgb array, so you need to include a reordering of the channel values, e.g. using the `imread` option.

Comment: While this is true, there is a horrendous amount of delay in rendering the image to the graph. The `imshow` feature of `matplotlib.pyplot` takes too long as it has to redraw the image every frame, thus meaning `cv2.waikey()` is better and does not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

you could do it on a thread by importing the Thread module with `from _thread import*` and use the `start_new_thread` method

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Do not vandalize your posts. By posting on this site, you've irrevocably granted the Stack Exchange network the right to distribute that content under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) for as long as it sees fit to do so. If you want to delete your answer, you can do so using the `Delete` button.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license (2.5/3.0/4.0)](//stackoverflow.com/help/licensing), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Comment: For deleting you need to register or flag your own post for a moderator to do the deleting for you.

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet will work without waiting for user input:

```py
blank_image = cv2.imread('blank.jpg')
cv2.namedWindow("bw", cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN)          
cv2.setWindowProperty("bw", cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, cv2.cv.CV_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)
cv2.imshow("bw", blank_image)
cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('0')
```

Follow [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35372700/whats-0xff-for-in-cv2-waitkey1) for more info.