# Using matplotlib.pyplot.imshow to display images to scale just like cv2.imshow

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, matplotlib

I am writing a tool to quickly scrub through a stream of images and mark down their timestamps if wanted. So I need to display an image and wait for user input using `raw_input` to decide whether to move forward/backward or save the timestamp. Sadly `cv2.imshow` requires a call to `cv2.waitkey` which doesn't work well together when I want to control what happens next, based on user input. So what I do now successively call `plt.imshow` which seems to clear the image it held out of memory and displays the next one, which is just what I want. A simplified example code would look something like this:

```
plt.ion()

def showimg(cvmat):
    plt.imshow(cvmat)
    i = raw_input()
    if i == 0:
        save_stamp()

for img in img_generator:
    showimg(img)
```

This is a very simplified illustration of what I am doing. I'd like to use `cv2.imshow` but for reasons unbeknownst to me [pyplot seems to work better](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32579899/6301103) when used with another breaking function. But when I plot with pyplot it doesn't preserve the true size of the image anymore and instead crops it to fit to some standard size it seems. What do I need to pass to `plt.imshow` so that it displays a cv::Mat as the true size of the image, just like `cv2.imshow`? I really only want the image to look the same, I actually don't mind the pyplot tools, like zoom and save.

Comment: maybe `plt.axis('image')` or 'same' (see the doc) ?

Comment: @scrx2 these options don't seem to do it for me. I don't want to scale the data but rather have the box and window be big enough to fit the entire image. So if my image is 1000 pixels high and 1600 pixels wide, I want the box that displays it be of these dimensions.

Comment: can you insert an image of the result you get?